# Not Able to launch Google Maps App from inside another app

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I am trying to open Google Maps App from inside an iOS App.

I am using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
```

but its not working. Can anyone tell me whats the issue?

Comment: is the app installed on your device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `canOpenURL` won't open an app. It just checks that the app can open the app or not. Use `openURL` method instead.

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]])
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
}
```

**Note:**

For opening a third party app using the URL Scheme. It should be installed on the device.

> **canOpenURL:**
>
> Returns whether an application can open a given URL resource.
>
> `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`
>
> *Parameters*
>
> **url**
>
> ```
> A URL object that identifies a given resource. The URL’s scheme—possibly a custom scheme—identifies which application can
> ```
>
> handle the URL.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> NO if no application is available that will accept the URL; otherwise,
>   returns YES.
>
> *Discussion*
>
> This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another
>   application will be launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that
>   the full URL is valid.

---

> **openURL**:
>
> Opens the resource at the specified URL.
>
> `- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url`
>
> *Parameters*
>
> **url**
>
> ```
> An object representing a URL (Universal Resource Locator). UIKit supports the http:, https:, tel:, and mailto: schemes.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the resource located by the URL was successfully opened;
>   otherwise NO.
>
> *Discussion*
>
> The URL can locate a resource in the same or other application. If the
>   resource is another application, invoking this method may cause the
>   calling application to quit so the other one can be launched.
>
> You may call canOpenURL: before calling this one to verify that there
>   is an application that can handle it.

Please refer [UIApplication Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @user2174560: With Pleasure :)